# Flow (typescript checker) configuration to follow symlinks on windows

Tags: javascript, typescript, js-of-ocaml

I cannot get [flow](https://flow.org/en/) (the facebook' type checker for javascript) to follow symbolic links directories created on Windows 10 (I do use Linux for this project, so not sure if it works there or not)

Flow documentation states that Symbolic links will be followed as long as they are also in the include path

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/

> " ... symlinks are followed as long as they lead to a file or
>   directory that is also included. .."

but using this .flowconfig (located at the root of my project (above the ./src folder)
Does not produce desired results -- still reports an error that

```
import {Something} from 'web_common/Something'
```

is invlalid.

.flowconfig :

```
[ignore]

.*/node_modules/.*
.*/build/.*
config-overrides.js
.*/src/registerServiceWorker.js
.*/src/index.js

.*/config-overrides.js


 [include]
    ./src/wc.src/



 [libs]
    flow-typed

 [lints]

 [options]

    all=true

    module.system.node.resolve_dirname=node_modules
    module.name_mapper='^react-native' ->'react-native-web'
    module.name_mapper='^web_common' ->'src/wc.src'


    esproposal.decorators=ignore
    esproposal.class_static_fields=enable
    esproposal.class_instance_fields=enable

    suppress_type=$FlowIssue
    suppress_type=$FlowFixMe



 [strict]
```

Is there a solution to this, or the Flow processor cannot be used on Windows with symlinked projects?

Answer (score 1):

I have this working now.
The solution was to make the
[include]   directory to point to the physical location of the symlinked directory
(and not to the symlink itself) .

So changing the above .flowconfig to

```
 [include]
    ../above_project_root_actual_location/wc.src/
```

fixed the problem